# Prove that $\mathbf S^2$ is a regular surface in $\mathbb R^3$

Tags: general-topology, geometry, differential-geometry, surfaces

I want to prove that the unit sphere $\mathbf{S}^2 = \{(x,y,z): x^2 + y^2 + z^2 = 1\}$ is a regular surface in $\Bbb R^3$, using strictly only the following definition. The task is to produce open sets $U,V$ and a map $\varphi$ satisfying the properties below.

> **(Surface.)** $S\subset \Bbb R^3$ is called a regular surface if for any $p\in S$, there exists an open set $U\subset \Bbb R^3$ containing $p$, an open set $V\subset \Bbb R^2$, and a differentiable$\color{red}{^1}$ map $\varphi: V\to U$ such that:
>
> 1. The restriction map $\varphi:V\to U\cap S$ is a homeomorphism.
> 2. For all $(x,y)\in V$, $D\varphi_{(x,y)}: \Bbb R^2\to\Bbb R^3$ (the derivative map of $\varphi$) is injective.

**My efforts:**
I am not sure, but I think we might be able to take the help of the stereographic projection at some stage. Firstly, I think it suffices to consider just $p = (0,0,1)$ due to the rotational symmetry of $\mathbf S^2$. We must find an open set $U \subset \Bbb R^3$ containing $p$, which satisfies the conditions above. My idea is to consider an open ball $B$ around $p$ (as in the figure below), and intuitively convince myself that the *patch* $B\cap \mathbf S^2$ is homeomorphic to a rectangle $V$ in $\Bbb R^2$. Hopefully, injectivity of $D\varphi_{(x,y)}$ for all $(x,y)\in V$ will also hold. However, it is difficult to explicitly pin these details down. Is there any other way out? If not, could I get some help in completing this attempt?

[image]

---

*Footnotes:*
$\color{red}{1.}$ $\varphi$ is differentiable in the sense that if $\varphi(u,v) = (\mathbf x(u,v), \mathbf y(u,v), \mathbf z(u,v))$ then $\mathbf x, \mathbf y, \mathbf z: \Bbb R^2\to\Bbb R$ have partial derivatives of all orders.

Comment: Not sure about your idea, but why don't you just you the stereographic map?  Let me remind you the following fact <br> The following map is a smooth diffeomorphism $$\begin{align} f:& \mathbb{R}^3\setminus \{0\} &\longrightarrow & \mathbb{R}^3\setminus \{0\}\\ & x &\mapsto & \left( \frac{x_1}{ \|x\|_2^2 },  \frac{x_2}{ \|x\|_2^2 }, \frac{x_3}{ \|x\|_2^2 }\right)\end{align} $$

Comment: Do you mean $\mathbf S^2$ instead of $\Bbb R^3\setminus \{0\}$ for the codomain of $f$? Also, how does this map help? I believe you are taking $\varphi = f$. What are $U,V$ then? @ParesseuxNguyen

Comment: Not really. With your $p$, I would take $\tilde{\phi}(x)= f( x- (0,0,-1) )$  on the domain $\mathbb{R}^3\setminus \{ (0,0,-1)\}$ . The homeomorphism is clear because $\phi \circ \phi = \text{Id}$. For the determinant condition, you can see that $\text{det}(D\tilde{\phi}) \ne 0$ (diffeomorphism) , hence $\delta_1 \tilde{\phi} , \delta_2 \tilde{\phi}$ are linearly independent, hence the injectivity.

Comment: Anyway, that is just a way to reason. You can obtain all that just by simple calculations and that's why I don't understand why you had troubles with those computations?

Comment: There is a little typo in my previous definition of $\tilde{\phi}$, it should be $ x \mapsto f( x-(0,0,-1))+(0,0,-1)$

Comment: Thanks! I was able to do it without the stereographic map also though (I completed the sketch of the proof in the attached link). Still thinking about how to see my original idea to completion. @ParesseuxNguyen

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a sketch of the proof [here](http://uregina.ca/%7Emareal/cs3.pdf), which I am adding as an answer.

---

It suffices to consider $p = (0,0, 1)$, due to the rotational symmetry of the sphere. Let $\mathbb H = \{(x,y,z)\in \mathbb S^2: z > 0\}$ and $\mathbb D= \{(x,y): x^2 + y^2 < 1\}$. Define $\pi: \mathbb H\to \mathbb D$ by $\pi: (x,y,z)\mapsto (x,y)$. $\pi$ is a continuous bijection with inverse $\varphi$ given by $$\pi^{-1}(x,y) = \varphi(x,y) = (x,y,\sqrt{1-x^2-y^2})$$
That $\varphi: \mathbb D\to \mathbb H$ is a homeomorphism is immediate from construction, since $\pi$ and $\varphi$ are both continuous and $\pi \circ \varphi = \text{id}_{\mathbb D}$ and $\varphi\circ\pi = \text{id}_{\mathbb H}$. Also,
$$D\varphi_{(x,y)}: (h,k) \mapsto \left(h, k, \frac{-xh-yk}{\sqrt{1-x^2 - y^2}} \right)$$
is injective.